# Problema com OnKeyPress e OnEnterKey

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estou com um problema, preciso pegar o valor digitado em um campo, pensei em usar `OnKeyPress` que chama a função `key_press` da seguinte maneira:

```
        var str;
        var keycode;
     function key_press(e) {
                var event = e.event, keyCode = event.key || String.fromCharCode(event.which);
                if (keyCode != "Enter") {
                    event = e.event, str = event.key || String.fromCharCode(event.which);
                    if (/^[\.\,e]$/.test(str))
                        event.preventDefault();
                }
        }
```

Até ai tudo ok, ele executa isso da maneira correta, eu acrescentei o `.OnEnterKey("enter")` para que ele execute a seguinte função :

```
        function enter() {
                for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(str); i++) {
                    $("#gridContainer2").dxDataGrid("addRow");
                }

        }
```

Qual o meu problema: na função `key_press` ele pega o valor que é passado sempre que um número é digitado, ou seja se eu digitar 1 ele pega normal, se eu digitar 8 também, porém quando passo 2 números isso já não da certo, pois a `var str` passa a receber o segundo digito que eu coloquei; ex: digitei 23 e dei `Enter` a `var str` recebe apenas o 3, pois executou a função `key_press` e recebeu 3, como eu posso pegar todo o valor do campo?? ex: digitei 15, quero que `str` receba `15` e execute o for de 0 a 14, andei pesquisando e disseram pra usar o seguinte : `document.getElementById("ID DO ELEMENTO").value`, mas sempre que uso isso, recebo valor `undefined`

Meu campo no formulário:

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().Form<FormaPagamentoViewModel>
    ()
    .ID("formularioCadastro")
    .ShowValidationSummary(false)
    .Items(items =>
    {
    items.AddGroup()
    .Items(groupItems =>
    {
    groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Fpg_quantidade)
    .Editor(e => e.NumberBox().ID("qua").Width("70px").OnKeyPress("key_press").OnEnterKey("enter")); //esse campo que estou usando
    });
    })
    .FormData(Model)
    )
```

Comment: armazena e vai concatenando o que vc digita numa var auxiliar, depois, no enter, vc passa a auxiliar. Entendeu?

Comment: O ideal seria chamar a função no blur, leave ou ainda deixar um intervalo no keyUp para identificar que o usuário parou de digitar e se o valor é válido

Comment: @cpll, é uma boa ideia, mas não sei como ir colocando em uma variável auxiliar os valores

Comment: @LeandroAngelo não sei fazer as coisas que você disse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por que você captura o valor do input a cada vez que o usuário aperta uma tecla se você só vai utiliza-lo quando apertar enter?

Não bastaria capturar esse valor uma vez na função enter?

```
function enter(e) {
    var str = e.event.path[0].value;
    for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(str); i++) {
        $("#gridContainer2").dxDataGrid("addRow");
    }
}
```

Nota: não conheço o método que você utilizou para adicionar o event listener, a forma com a qual eu acessei o valor do input é apenas uma dedução baseada no código que você postou.

> andei pesquisando e disseram pra usar o seguinte :
>   document.getElementById("ID DO ELEMENTO").value, mas sempre que uso
>   isso, recebo valor undefined

Você provavelmente está usando da forma errada, mas não tem como dizer sem o código.

Comment: Vou testar amanhã cedo, pois o código está no pc da empresa, mas eu preciso realizar aquele código sempre que digitar uma tecla para verificação de caracteres, mas não sabia outra maneira de pegar dados, vou testar amanha cedo essa maneira que você falou

Comment: Essa maneira que você me disse, eu consigo pegar o segundo elemento, por exemplo, se digito 10, pego o 0, se digito 15, pego o 5, quer q eu poste o código todo?